# Django error: list index out of range (when there's no objects)

Tags: python, django

Everything works fine until I delete all the objects and try to trigger the url, then it gives me this `traceback: list index out of range`. I can't use `get` because there might be more than one object and using `[0]` with `filter` leads me to this error when there's no object present, any way around this? I'm trying to get the recently created object of the Ticket model (if created that is) and then perform the logic, so that if the customer doesn't have any tickets, nothing happens but if the customer does then the logic happens

Models

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Views

```
try:
    ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id")[0]
    now = datetime.now().date()
    set_date = ticket.date_posted
    check_time = now - set_date <= timedelta(hours=24)
    if check_time:
        print('working')
    else:
        print('not working')
except Ticket.DoesNotExist:
    ticket = None

context = {"check_time": check_time}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id")[0]
```

Use this using [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) which is a very efficient way if there is any object exist in DB:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id")
if tickets.exists():
   ticket = tickets.first()
else:
   ticket = None
```

### Update

You can do the query inside the filter function.

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer, date_posted__lte=timezone.now().date() - timedelta(hours=24))

context = {"check_time": tickets.exists()}
```

Comment: now that `check_time` is gonna be inside of the if statement, how would I call it in context?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can do this checking within the filter function

Comment: yh but I would still require the context tho, cuz I need to pass it to the template

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id").first() or None
if ticket is not None:    
    now = datetime.now().date()
    set_date = ticket.date_posted
    check_time = now - set_date <= timedelta(hours=24)
    if check_time:
        print('working')
    else:
        print('not working')
    context = {"check_time": check_time}
```

instead of:

```
ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id")[0]
```

Comment: but doing this would give me `none type no attribute date_posted` error, how would I fix that?

Comment: You need to check the value returned. if ticket is not None: do something...